# Beeline to hiveserver 2 : Required field 'serverProtocolVersion' is unset error

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am getting the following error when trying to connect from beeline to hiveserver2

```
Error: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default:     Required field 'serverProtocolVersion' is unset!
```

I am on hadoop2.7.3, hive 2.1.1, beeline client from spark 2.1.0 for hadoop 2.7 all running on Mac OS-X 10 with hive-jdbc-2.1.1-standalone.jar

The same error also in the later part of the message mentions the following

```
(User: hv is not allowed to impersonate anonymous), serverProtocolVersion:null)
```

I have set the following in hive-site.xml

```
  <property>
     <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
      <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hive.server2.enable.authentication</name>
       <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
       <value>NONE</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
       <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
       <value>true</value>
       <description>
       ...
       </description>
   </property>
```

and the following in core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hv.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hv.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Not sure if serverProtocolError is causing the impersonation issue or otherwise. Pl help

Comment: Can you post the command used to connect using beeline?

Answer (score 0):

Please try it by setting below property in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.allow.user.substitution</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks Satish, I am still getting both the errors. 'serverProtocolVersion is not set' and 'user hv cannot impersonate anonymous'.

Comment: Not sure if these are two independent issues or one causing the other.

Comment: the default value for hive.server2.allow.user.substitution is true.  so unless it was changed, setting it true would do nothing.